# Meshcat not showing the changes to a Free Body's Pose

Tags: python, drake

I've been trying to create my own ManipulationStation for a different robot arm using Pydrake, but I've been unsuccessful so far in adding clutter to my ManipulationStation. For some odd reason, Meshcat won't show the updated poses of my objects.

```
import numpy as np
import glob
from pydrake.geometry import MeshcatVisualizerCpp
from pydrake.math import RigidTransform, RotationMatrix
from pydrake.systems.analysis import Simulator

from pydrake.systems.framework import DiagramBuilder

from pydrake.all import (
    DiagramBuilder, FindResourceOrThrow,
    SceneGraph, Diagram,
    MultibodyPlant, Parser, Simulator, MeshcatVisualizerCpp, 
    UniformlyRandomRotationMatrix, RandomGenerator)

from pydrake.geometry import Meshcat 

class DexterPPStation(Diagram):
    def __init__(self, time_step, file_path):
        super().__init__()
        self.time_step = time_step
        self.path = file_path
        self.plant = MultibodyPlant(self.time_step)
        self.scene_graph = SceneGraph()
        self.plant.RegisterAsSourceForSceneGraph(self.scene_graph)
        self.controller_plant = MultibodyPlant(self.time_step)
        self.object_ids = []
        self.object_poses = []
        
    def AddObject(self, file, name, pose):
        model_idx = Parser(self.plant).AddModelFromFile(file, name)
        indices = self.plant.GetBodyIndices(model_idx)
        self.object_ids.append(indices[0])
        self.object_poses.append(pose)

        return model_idx

    def CreateBins(self, path, XP_B1, XP_B2):
        bin1 = Parser(self.plant).AddModelFromFile(path, "bin1")
        self.plant.WeldFrames(self.plant.world_frame(), self.plant.GetFrameByName("bin_base", bin1), XP_B1)
  
        bin2 = Parser(self.plant).AddModelFromFile(path, "bin2")
        self.plant.WeldFrames(self.plant.world_frame(), self.plant.GetFrameByName("bin_base", bin2), XP_B2)

    def CreateRandomPickingObjects(self, n = 4):
        choices = [f for f in glob.glob("/opt/drake/share/drake/manipulation/models/ycb/sdf/*.sdf")]
        z = 0.1
        rs = np.random.RandomState()
        generator = RandomGenerator(rs.randint(1000))
        for i in range(n):
            obj = choices[i]
            pose = RigidTransform(
                UniformlyRandomRotationMatrix(generator),  
                [rs.uniform(.35,0.6), rs.uniform(-.2, .2), z])
   
            model = self.AddObject(obj, obj.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0] + str(i), pose)
            body_idx = self.plant.GetBodyIndices(model)[0]
            self.object_ids.append(body_idx)
            self.object_poses.append(pose)
            z+=0.1
 
    def SetRandomPoses(self, station_context):
        plant_context = self.GetSubsystemContext(self.plant, station_context)
        for i in range(len(self.object_ids)):
            self.plant.SetFreeBodyPose(plant_context, self.plant.get_body(self.object_ids[i]), self.object_poses[i])
   
    def Finalize(self):
        self.plant.Finalize()
        self.controller_plant.Finalize()
        builder = DiagramBuilder()
        

        builder.AddSystem(self.plant)
        builder.AddSystem(self.controller_plant)
        builder.AddSystem(self.scene_graph)

        builder.Connect(self.plant.get_geometry_poses_output_port(), self.scene_graph.get_source_pose_port(self.plant.get_source_id()))
        builder.Connect(self.scene_graph.get_query_output_port(), self.plant.get_geometry_query_input_port())
        builder.ExportOutput(self.scene_graph.get_query_output_port(), "query_object")
        builder.ExportOutput(self.plant.get_geometry_poses_output_port(), "geometry_poses")

        builder.ExportOutput(self.scene_graph.get_query_output_port(), "geometry_query")

        builder.ExportOutput(self.plant.get_contact_results_output_port(),"contact_results")
        builder.ExportOutput(self.plant.get_state_output_port(),"plant_continuous_state")
        builder.BuildInto(self)
```

To test my code, I've been running the script below.

```
def test():
    builder = DiagramBuilder()
    station = DexterPPStation(1e-4, "drake/manipulation/models/final_dexter_description/urdf/dexter.urdf")

    station.CreateBins("/opt/drake/share/drake/examples/manipulation_station/models/bin.sdf", RigidTransform(np.array([0.5,0,0])), RigidTransform(np.array([0,0.5,0])))
    station.CreateRandomPickingObjects(1)
    
    station.Finalize()
    builder.AddSystem(station)
    station_context = station.CreateDefaultContext()
    station.SetRandomPoses(station_context)
    
    MeshcatVisualizerCpp.AddToBuilder(builder, station.GetOutputPort("query_object"), meshcat)

    diagram = builder.Build()
    simulator = Simulator(diagram)
    simulator.set_target_realtime_rate(1.0)
    simulator.AdvanceTo(0.1)

test()
```

I've tried to call the `SetRandomPoses()` function from inside my Finalize() method, but since I needed to pass in a context to the function, I wasn't sure what to do. I'm new to Drake, so any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've created a `station_context` and set it to the random poses, but then you don't use it anywhere.  When you create the `simulator`, it is creating another `Context` (with the default values), which is getting published when you call `AdvanceTo`.

The solution here, I think, is to not create your own `station_context`, but do e.g.

```
simulator = Simulator(diagram)
diagram_context = simulator.get_mutable_context()
station_context = station.GetMyMutableContextFromRoot(diagram_context)
station.SetRandomPoses(station_context)
```

then you can call `AdvanceTo`.